# Facebook OAuthException code 190 subcode 490 - user is enrolled in a blocking, logged-in checkpoint

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Well the title says it all. Does anyone have an idea what the **code 190,  subcode 490** means? (Error validating access token: The user is enrolled in a blocking, logged-in checkpoint) It does not appear in the  [official facebook developer error code documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#errors) and not on the [inofficial wiki page](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes) I dug up on SO.

The token in question is used to manage a fanpage for a user (post stuff, change title picture, etc.). For most users this error does not happen but for some it will show with no clue to where the difference might be.

The request that caused the error was a POST to `pageId/feed`.

We're using Graph API version 2.0

Comment: It means the user account is currently flagged by Facebook’s security algorithms, for being hacked or that someone might have tried to hack it. They will most likely have to take additional steps the next time they login to Facebook, to prove their identity.

Comment: I have encountered the same error just a couple days back. Any idea what could be causing these security checks to trigger? I mean it is possible that it is an actual hacking attempt, but it considering the timing and the amount of posts I can find with the actual error message, the appearance of this might be interpreted suggest something else? Doesn't help that this error message is not documented anywhere.

Comment: I have noticed this many times in a short period. Uploaded an image of my passport when this occurs. The account will be unlocked after a few days, if you're lucky. Have not even used the Graph API extensively, just trying out the online Graph Explorer tool.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was solved simply by logging in to the [Business Manager](https://business.facebook.com).

I had to be notified that some content was removed because of copyright violation and agree to be a good boy.
Couple of "continue" buttons - and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 3):

Another suggestion if anyone gets this issue. I was messaging a user back from a page I own and I was seeing this very message. I had a Facebook Page with a Facebook App, created in the Facebook Developers area. The access token for the app needed regenerating.

I did this by going to Facebook Developer, selecting the app I was working with, clicking the Messenger tab for the list of enabled products for this app, and then selecting re-generate token. Copying the new token made it work first time.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As `@CBoe` mentioned,it means the user **account** is currently **flagged** by Facebook’s security algorithms. I got this message when logged in several times in different place. Once your account become origin and can login successfully, it will disappear.